# using java to get xsl message

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I'm trying to print the `<xsl:message>` in a JTextArea using JAXP.
My Problem is, that I can't create a saxonica Controller with my transformer and I don't know why because I'm using TransformerFactoryImpl as in some answers is called.

Here is my Java Code:

```
public static void xslTransform(File xmlFile,File xslFile, JTextArea output){
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xslFile);
TransformerFactoryImpl tfimpl = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
Transformer transformer = tfimpl.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslFile));
Controller controller = new Controller(transformer);
```

import for Controller:

```
net.sf.saxon.Controller;
```

Hope anybody can help me.

KaFu

Comment: there's a "xsl:message" missing in the first line.

Comment: I've edited to fix this. For future reference you can treat text as "verbatim" without angle brackets being interpreted as html tags by enclosing the relevant bit in backquotes.

Comment: thanks =)) that's my first post

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `.newInstance()`, i.e. just call `tfimpl.newTransformer`?  The `.newInstance()` is a static method on `TransformerFactory` that is used to find an implementation of `TransformerFactory` and instantiate it, you don't need to do that as you already have an instance.

Answer (score 4):

There has never been a constructor on the Controller class that took a JAXP Transformer as a parameter, I don't know where you got that idea from.

In releases prior to Saxon 9.6, you can cast the Transformer to a Controller if you want to call methods on the Controller object, that is

```
Controller controller = (Controller)transformer;
```

In 9.6, the relationship between Controller and Transformer has changed, because the JAXP API is becoming increasingly unsuitable to take advantage of the facilities becoming available in XSLT 3.0. You can now cast the Transformer to `net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl`, and from the TransformerImpl you can call `getUnderlyingController()` to get to the Controller.

But do you really want to do it this way? An alternative would be to do

```
factory.setAttribute(FeatureKeys.MESSAGE_EMITTER_CLASS, MyMessageEmitter.class)
```

where MyMessageEmitter is your implementation of Saxon's MessageEmitter inferface.

Comment: could you show me an example with the maybe easier way factory.setAttribute(...)? Best with the message as string? Sorry, I do not have any experience with java and xslt...

Comment: I got a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MESSAGE_EMITTER_CLASS class must be a String in line "factory.setAttribute(...);

Comment: Yes, sorry, it must be the name of the class, not the actual class.

Comment: thanks a lot I got it =) 
But now I have the next problem. How to got these as String to put it into the TextArea?

Comment: If it's a new problem, please ask it in a new question (and make it free-standing).