# print xsl:message as String in TextArea

Tags: java, xslt

i'm trying to print a xsl:message in a JTextArea. I know I have to use a MessageEmitter
Here is my Java Code:

```
public static void xslTransform(File xmlFile,File xslFile, JTextArea output){
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
TransformerFactory transFact = new TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transFact.setAttribute(FeatureKeys.MESSAGE_EMITTER_CLASS, "net.sf.saxon.serialize.MessageEmitter");
Transformer transformer = transFact.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslFile));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Can anybody help me to get a String from the `<xsl:message>` ?

This is my current Code:

```
public static void xslTransform(File xmlFile)throws IOException, TransformerException{
File xslFile = ...;
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
StreamSource xslSource = new StreamSource(xslFile);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult (new StringWriter()); //maybe here is the problem?
TransformerFactory transformerFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFact.setAttribute(FeatureKeys.MESSAGE_EMITTER_CLASS, "MyMessageEmitter");
Transformer transformer = transformerFact.newTransformer(xslSource);
transformer.transform(xmlSource,result);
}
```

MyMessageEmitter Class:

```
public class MyMessageEmitter extends net.sf.saxon.serialize.MessageEmitter{
String message;
private StringWriter stwriter = new StringWriter();
public void MyMessageEmitter() throws XPathException{
setWriter(stwriter);
}
@Override
public void close() throws XPathException{
super.close();
message=stwriter.toString();
System.out.println(message);
stwriter = new StringWriter();
}
}
```

why is message now all the time null?

KaFu

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420589/using-java-to-get-xsl-message)?

Comment: In my last question I did not know how to implement the message emitter. Now I do not know how to get the string from the implemented emitter. Also they told I should create a new message for my new Problem. =) I edited the last question before they told I should create a new question.

Comment: Fair enough. I've rolled back the edit on the other question so it is consistent with the answer.

Comment: thanks for doing this =)

Answer (score 0):

The class you have nominated as the message emitter is the standard Saxon message emitter, but what you want to do is to implement your own. Something like this:

```
public static class MyMessageEmitter extends net.sf.saxon.serialize.MessageEmitter {

   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

   public MyMessageEmitter() {
     setWriter(writer);
   }

   public void close() {
     super.close();
     String message = writer.toString();
     // now do what you want with the message
     writer = new StringWriter(); // ready for the next message
   }
}
```

then...

```
transFact.setAttribute(FeatureKeys.MESSAGE_EMITTER_CLASS, "MyMessageEmitter");
```

This would actually be a bit easier using Saxon's s9api interface rather than JAXP, and if you were a more experienced Java programmer I would point you in that direction, but as you're new to the game it's probably easier to take small steps.

Comment: that look's really really good, but my writer is always null, I edit the question with my current code. Hope you can tell me what's wrong...

Comment: I suggest you try to put together a repro: that is a free-standing program which demonstrates the problem, in a form that other people can run. It's very difficult to debug other people's code if the code isn't provided in runnable form.

Comment: i got my mistake, it writes the output of the xsl but not the message!! I need one more time help... My xsl changes the xml and my output is a "new" xml, but also there are '<xsl:message>' tags in my xslt and this is what i want to print in a textArea. How does it work? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Please raise a new question that tells us exactly what you are doing and how it is failing.